# Is there any documented Yammer API to get all groups for currents user?

Tags: rest, sharepoint-online, yammer

Is there any documented Yammer API to get all groups for currents user?
I can use 
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups.json?mine=1
or 
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/current.json?include_group_memberships=true

But none of them are documented on Yammer Documentation and they might become unsupported anytime (the second one is documented but the include_group_memberships parameter is not documented )

are you guys aware of any documented way of doing it?